# Error Subscribing to Pusher Presence channel from Android

Tags: android, pusher

I am trying to subscribe to a presence channel from an Android Client, but I keep on failing the authentication part. I can subscribe to a normal channel with no problem. 
Connecting to pusher:

```
      try {
            authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer("http://test.xxxx.io/pusher/auth");
            authorizer.setHeaders(getHeaders());
            PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setEncrypted(true).setAuthorizer(authorizer);

            pusher = new Pusher(JWTHelper.pusherKey, options);
            pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() + " from " + change.getPreviousState());
                    if (change.getCurrentState().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Try to connect to presence channel.");
                        connectToChannels(pusher);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "There was a problem connecting to Pusher." + message);
                }
            }, ConnectionState.ALL);

            if (pusher.getConnection().getState() == ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
                pusher.connect();
            } else if (pusher.getConnection().getState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                pusher.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pusher exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Then I try to subscribe to a channel (works) and to a presence channel (this is where it doesn't work):

```
String socketId = pusher.getConnection().getSocketId();
Log.d(TAG, "socket id: " + socketId);
HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("socket_id", socketId);
parameters.put("channel_name", "presence-mod_111");
authorizer.setQueryStringParameters(parameters);

// test. this works
pusher.subscribe("account_111");

// error
pusher.subscribePresence("presence-mod_111");
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
State changed to CONNECTING from DISCONNECTED
(standard input):D/TEST( 6949): State changed to CONNECTED from CONNECTING
(standard input):D/TEST( 6949): Try to connect to presence channel.
(standard input):D/TEST( 6949): (in method)socket id: 45048.110272
(standard input):D/TEST( 7676): connect to account 111...
(standard input):D/TEST( 7676): State changed to CONNECTING from DISCONNECTED
(standard input):D/TEST( 7676): connection..null
(standard input):D/TEST( 7676): State changed to CONNECTED from CONNECTING
(standard input):D/TEST( 7676): Try to connect to presence channel.
(standard input):D/TEST( 7676): (in method)socket id: 45142.76981
(standard input):D/TEST( 9258): State changed to CONNECTING from DISCONNECTED
(standard input):D/TEST( 9258): State changed to CONNECTED from CONNECTING
(standard input):D/TEST( 9258): Try to connect to presence channel.
(standard input):D/TEST( 9258): socket id: 45107.97746
(standard input):D/TEST( 9258): arg0 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://test.xxx.com/pusher/auth, arg1: com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://test.xxx.com/pusher/auth
```

I have no more ideas, any hint would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to a presence channel the library needs to authenticate the subscription against a server (there needs to be an authority that is generally a server).

You can see this authentication attempt in the logs:

> http://test.xxx.com/pusher/auth, arg1: com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://test.xxx.com/pusher/auth

There are two solutions to this:

1. Set the auth endpoint to a valid endpoint and implement the [authentication mechanism](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_presence_endpoints). You can find an example of the client code [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pusher/client/example/PresenceChannelExampleApp.java).
2. Define your own Authorizer which creates the authentication token in some other way. See `setAuthorizer` on the [Pusher Java Client README](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java#the-pusher-constructor)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. The endpoint exists, because the .js client can connect to it. Just for my connection from android it doesn't work. Do I need to set a special header parameter in the authorizer object?

Comment: @GabrielaRadu what you use to authenticate is entirely up to you. It really depends on your application login process. How does your app know who the current user is? It should pass that information as part of the authentication callback. Using the [HttpAuthorizer](http://pusher.github.io/pusher-websocket-java/com/pusher/client/util/HttpAuthorizer.html) you can set either headers or query string parameters.